# Configure systemd timer to run every hour after first run

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have a service that runs every hour (using **OnCalendar=hourly**). This works great *if* the system is on 24/7, but gets messed up after coming out of suspend/hibernation. The service will run immediately - which is what I want - but then it runs again at the top of each hour, regardless of how much time has elapsed since the last run.

Is there a way to configure timers to run in 1-hour intervals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see detailed examples into the [Arch-wiki for systemd timers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd/Timers).

For your case, you can use a *monotonic timer*, something like:

```
[Timer]
OnBootSec=1min
OnUnitActiveSec=1h
```

The *realtime timer* `OnCalendar=hourly` will run after boot (for the missed hour, because of your `Persistent=true` I guess) and then will follow fixed datetime values, so as you describe, the interval between the first two runs after boot, can be less than an hour.

But you maybe don't want to use the monotonic timer, although it is covering what you want about suspendings, if you don't want this behaviour when rebooting. `Persistent=false` would fit for your case then, but all runs will be on fixed times.

Comment: I tried both "Persistent=" settings and neither worked. I'll give this a test and let you know.

Comment: I added a small update. What about reboots (not suspends)? It always run at boot with the first case.

Comment: I only reboot when I update the system, so the hourly timer has already triggered. Like I said, I don't care if the timer runs after suspend/reboot at 8:59, just don't want it to run again at 9:00.

Comment: Then probably hourly, no Persistent, don't run at boot, only at fixed times. If avoiding close runs is more important. I mean if rebooting at 8:10, you 'll run 8:00,8:10,9:10 etc with the first. 8 and 9 with no persistent & hourly.

Comment: OK, using `OnUnitActiveSec=1h` and removing `OnCalendar=` seems to have worked. Thanks!